What is the difference between "cp /tmp/a ./" and "cp /tmp/a ."
What is the difference between cp /tmp/a ./ and cp /tmp/a . (i.e. with and without the trailing slash in destination)?
They both mean copying /tmp/a to current directory, but I see some people insist using . (without trailing slash), and I don't understand the difference.
Are the 2 commands 100% identical?

In the specific case they are identical. In the general sense they are not necessarily identical. Let's label them:

cp /tmp/a ./
cp /tmp/a .

Let's also bring in two similar cases:

cp /tmp/a x/
cp /tmp/a x

First up, note that this answer cannot be generalised across all commands. It's true for cp and many core commands, but you cannot necessarily apply it everywhere. For example rsync -a foo bar and rsync -a foo/ bar do different things (although bar and bar/ act the same). Most commands don't care much but some do have special behaviour where a trailing / indicates a directory.
Now to the explanation.
On all systems, (1) and (2) are identical, because . can only be a directory. They tell the system to copy the non-directory /tmp/a to the current directory, overwriting any existing non-directory a.
Option (3) clearly tells the system to copy the non-directory item /tmp/a to the directory x that's in the current directory, overwriting any existing non-directory item a already present in x.
For option (4), however, there is a potential ambiguity where x may or may not be a directory (and indeed, may not even exist). If x is a directory then option (3) applies. Otherwise the instruction is to copy the non-directory /tmp/a to the current directory, creating x or overwriting any existing non-directory x - much like options (1) and (2).
Conclusion
Because option (3) with its trailing / is clear in its objective (and will trigger an error if the named destination is not a directory), some people prefer to provide a trailing directory slash for any directory destination, even when there cannot be any other meaning. So they will write ./ for consistency even though . can only be a directory.
Notes
In all cases, if the source (/tmp/a) is a directory the cp command will fail an error such as cp: -r not specified; omitting directory '/tmp/a'.

Thanks for the detailed explanation. Appreciated!

With (4.), if x doesn't exist in the current directory (either as a directory or file), and /tmp/a is a file, then the file x will be created in the current directory. This can be confusing if there isn't a directory x and (4.) was meant to copy the file /tmp/a to a directory x - it will instead create a file x with the contents of /tmp/a. The command (3.) is unambiguous - if there isn't a directory x, and (3.) is attempted, the command will fail with Not a directory. I believe this is one of the reasons why autocomplete with Tab adds / to directories.

@Vilinkameni I've extended the answer a little, but I don't think it is materially different. Yet I'm not sure what you're adding with your concerns. It's possible to specify that the destination must be a directory, but it's not possible to specify that the destination must not be a directory, and so there is unavoidable ambiguity in my option (4)

My comment was mostly about the case when there is neither a file nor a directory named x.
